# How do I upgrade Angular CLI for the Production Server?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and want to know what is the process for deploying an Angular application that was updated from version 6 to 8 using Angular CLI, but the DEV/QA servers still have old version of CLI.

I updated my Angular application from version 6 to 8 locally and the it ran without errors.  Now I am ready to deploy it to the Dev and QA servers for testing, but I am not clear if I need to upgrade the CLI version on both the Dev/QA servers as well.  If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. can you please share the errors that you are getting.

Comment: I was curious if a deployment of a new ANGULAR CLI is required for the Development server.  I didn’t have any error within my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cli is only used for development and building, you do not need to have the cli deployed on the machine that hosts the production builds.

If you have a CI pipeline that does builds for you then the build server would normally get the correct cli from the package.json file as it does an NPM install.

The final build is just a bunch of static files that can be hosted on a plain old web server with no reliance on NPM or the cli.